# Yii-User and Yii-eauth integration

Tags: authentication, yii, oauth, widget

I am trying to put together an application using `yii-user` and `yii-eauth` extensions but I am coming up short. When I create a new webapp and install eauth I can get it to work fine so I know that I am not doing anything wrong on that end. I think the problem lies with my urls. This is a demo of what it is supposed to be like: http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo/login. When someone clicks on say google it should bring you to the google sign in page but on my application I am getting a 404 error that states `"The system is unable to find the requested action "login"."` The url for this is `user/user/login/service/google_oauth` whereas the url should read `user/login/service/google_oauth`. Upon typing this into the browser manually I am redirected to the right page.

So I took a look into the `EAuthWidget.php` class to see if I could find out where it was getting that extra "user" from but I could not figure it out. I think it may have something to do with the fact that I have this in the user module which is in the `/modules/user` directory in my webapp. I also tried to use the `URLManager` to point to the right address but with no luck.

Does anyone have any similar experiences setting this up? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the widget initialization code in your view(namely change the `action` property of the widget), somewhat like this:

```
<h2>Do you already have an account on one of these sites? Click the logo to log in with it here:</h2>
<?php 
  $this->widget('ext.eauth.EAuthWidget', array('action' => 'login'));
?>
```

Just to add, keep in mind that this action depends on *which view* you are including this widget, if the view is *protected/views/site/login.php* (which is yii's default site login view) then action should be able to go to the yii-user module's login action, so it'll be : `'action'=>'/user/login'` , however if you are including this widget in yii-user's *protected/modules/user/views/user/login.php* then the action will be `'login'` as already mentioned.

Comment: do ask for clarifications if needed, and let me know how it works out

Comment: Awesome! It worked just as you described. Maybe I should go back to reading the API more carefully! Now I just have to figure out whats wrong with the redirect URI and I will be good to go. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help. catching errors such as this will become easier with more experience in the framework, so keep coding, cheers!