# Misunderstanding of using Yii eauth extension

Tags: php, yii, oauth

I am using [yii eauth extension](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth/) in my yii project for login via social accounts. I read documentation from github and [russian version](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129804/) also, but I didn't understand how to use that extension. Maybe that code:

```
$serviceName = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('service');
if (isset($serviceName)) {
    /** @var $eauth EAuthServiceBase */
    $eauth = Yii::app()->eauth->getIdentity($serviceName);
    $eauth->redirectUrl = Yii::app()->user->returnUrl;
    $eauth->cancelUrl = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('site/sociallogin');

    try {
        if ($eauth->authenticate()) {
            //var_dump($eauth->getIsAuthenticated(), $eauth->getAttributes());
            $identity = new EAuthUserIdentity($eauth);

            // successful authentication
            if ($identity->authenticate()) {
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
                //var_dump($identity->id, $identity->name, Yii::app()->user->id);exit;

                // special redirect with closing popup window
                $eauth->redirect();
            }
            else {
                // close popup window and redirect to cancelUrl
                $eauth->cancel();
            }
        }

        // Something went wrong, redirect to login page
        //$this->redirect(array('site/login2'));
        $this->render('login2',  array());
    }
    catch (EAuthException $e) {
        // save authentication error to session
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'EAuthException: '.$e->getMessage());

        // close popup window and redirect to cancelUrl
        $eauth->redirect($eauth->getCancelUrl());
    }
}

// default authorization code through login/password ..
$this->render('login2',  array());
```

**Questions:**

1) What is the difference between `$eauth->authenticate()` and `$identity->authenticate()`?

2) Where is the "users" table for logged-in users' settings kept?

I read this [simular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729779/yii-user-and-yii-eauth-integration) already, it isn't what I need. Sorry if I ask easy question but I realy need a help ! Thanks in advance for any response from you!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    $serviceName = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('service');
    if (isset($serviceName)) {
        /** @var $eauth \nodge\eauth\ServiceBase */
        $eauth = Yii::$app->get('eauth')->getIdentity($serviceName);
        $eauth->setRedirectUrl(Yii::$app->getUser()->getReturnUrl());
        $eauth->setCancelUrl(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/sociallogin'));

        try {
            if ($eauth->authenticate()) {

                $identity = User::findByEAuth($eauth);
                Yii::$app->getUser()->login($identity);

                // special redirect with closing popup window
                $eauth->redirect();
            }
            else {
                // close popup window and redirect to cancelUrl
                $eauth->cancel();
            }
        }
        catch (\nodge\eauth\ErrorException $e) {
            // save error to show it later
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'EAuthException: '.$e->getMessage());

            $eauth->redirect($eauth->getCancelUrl());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but, where is the deal, I did not undestand how work the authenticate process

Comment: I know basic things about the lib, but I didn't know specific informations and the most important thing is: How can I set table name. does there exist any config file, any constants or some piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions.

1) What is the difference between $eauth->authenticate() and $identity->authenticate()?

[The EAuth extension allows to authenticate users with accounts on **other** websites.](https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth)

Here is the [demo](http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo/login). We see this a lot with sign in using your facebook account.

Supported protocols: OpenID, OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0.

EAuth is a extension for provide a unified (does not depend on the selected service) method to authenticate the user. So, the extension **itself does not perform login**, does not register the user and does not bind the user accounts from different providers.

2) Where is the "users" table for logged-in users' settings kept?

This of course would vary from project to project as my project doesn't have current logged-in users, but you could add that into your project.